# Represent a function by a mathematical function

Tags: python, math

Is it possible to output a mathematical function directly from the function implementation ?

```
class MyFunction:
    def __init__(self, func):
        self.func = func
    def math_representation(self):
        # returns a string representation of self.func

f = lambda x: 3*x**2
myFunc = MyFunction(f)
print(myFunc.math_reprentation()) #prints something like 3*x**2
```

Of course constructing the object with the representation as a parameter is possible, and is a trivial solution. But the idea is to generate this representation.
I could also build the function with objects representing the math operations, but the idea is to do it on a regular (lambda) function.

I really don't see a way for this to happen, but I'm curious.
Thanks for any help and suggestion

Comment: Not directly like that, but you might get to something you like using [Sympy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html)

Comment: If you restrict your functions, eg only permit polynomials, then it's fairly easy to do it yourself.

Comment: I don't have any restrictions on the function, but the Sympy library seems to be fine for my needs. Apparently, I can construct my function and get the math representation, and then produce the lambda function that I need to run my program. Thank you very much for your help !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As I said, you can use [SymPy](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/functions/index.html) if you want this to be more complex, but for simple functions (and trusted inputs), you could do something like this:

```
class MathFunction(object):
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.code = code
        self._func = eval("lambda x: " + code)
    def __call__(self, arg):
        return self._func(arg)
    def __repr__(self):
        return "f(x) = " + self.code
```

You can use it like this:

```
>>> sq = MathFunction("x**2")
>>> sq
f(x) = x**2
>>> sq(7)
49
```

This is a bit restricted, of course (only using the variable called "x", and only one parameter), but it can be, of course, expanded.

Comment: I don't really like this exact solution, but the SymPy library is fine ! Thank you very much.